# Integrating Parachain-Staking Pallet in Solochain: Transitioning from POA to Proof of Stake

Tags: parachain, staking, solo-chain, poa, proof-of-stake

Is it possible to integrate the parachain-staking pallet into my solochain? I want to transition my chain's consensus mechanism from POA to proof of stake using a parachain-staking pallet in my solochain. Can I use that?

For your reference, here is the code of parachain-staking pallet:
https://github.com/moonbeam-foundation/moonbeam/tree/master/pallets/parachain-staking

Comment: Solochain already have NPOS consensus, just clone https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/substrate, and run this why you want the consensus of moonbeam.

Comment: we need to use DPOS instead of NPOS. Moonbeams pallet giving DPOS feature

Comment: If you want DPOS you can cosmos instead of substrate it has DPOS as its consensus, I didn't get any point in changing the current consensus of substrate

Comment: Could you elaborate on what do you mean for `parachain-staking pallet` ? Do you refer to the FRAME staking pallet? (https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/substrate/frame/staking)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Moonbeam's parachain-staking pallet for DPOS just by reading the pallet's README. You could also consider FRAME's [Staking pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/master/substrate/frame/staking), which is generic over the underlying election algorithm. You'd need to implement your own [election provider](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L120) to return an election result that is calculated using DPOS.

FRAME's Staking pallet is non trivial though, so keep that in mind.